# Force span to occupy 2 lines

Tags: html, css

I have multiple divs that have some image and span contents inside. The height of the div is determined by the contents but the problem I am having is the divs tend to differ in height due to the text. Some span's value occupies 2 lines because the text is long while some only single line.

What I need is to force all short-texted spans to occupy 2 lines, or maybe is there a better layout alternative for this to make sure all divs are of equal height regardless of length of the span?

Thanks.

Comment: define the width for span.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add `display: block;` to all spans and define a height.

Comment: Thank you, that was simpler than I thought it would be!